# List index out of range error while performing a binary search

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I attempted to create a function that takes an ordered list of numbers and a given number, and decides whether or not the given number is inside the list. I am trying to use a binary search to accomplish this task.

I have two steps:

First, I am making `list1` smaller by only taking the numbers in `list1` that are smaller than the given number, and then appending those numbers into a new list, called `newlist`.

Next, in the `while` loop, I am basically taking all the numbers that are less than the number in the middle of the `newlist` and removing them, repeating that process multiple times until there is only one number in `newlist`. From there, I would compare that number to the given number. My code is shown below.

```
list1 = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 14, 17, 29, 31]
number = 7

def func(list1, number):
    newlist = []
    for x in list1:
        if x < number:
            newlist.append(x)
        else:
            continue

    while len(newlist) > 1:
        for x in range(0, len(newlist) - 1):
            if newlist[x] < newlist[round(len(newlist) / 2)]:
                newlist.remove(newlist[x])
            else:
                continue

    if newlist[0] == number:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(func(list1, number))
```

I am receiving an error at line 36 (`if newlist[x] < newlist[round(len(newlist) / 2)]:`), that the list index is out of range. I think that the problem is that as `newlist` is getting smaller and smaller, the `x` value set by `range(0, len(newlist) - 1)` is staying the same?? If that is the case, I am unsure of how to remedy that. Much thanks in advance.

Comment: So it's not an option to use `number in list1` check?

Comment: Although this might not be a direct answer, but at this point, I'd really really encourage you to try out the debugger, if you haven't already. Just insert the line: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before the line with `if` and re-run the program as usual. In the prompt that appears, type `!<python expression to evaluate>` (like `!newlist[x]`, or `!x` etc) to see the values of the variables. Type `c` to continue running the program until the end or another breakpoint, or type `n` to execute the next line and stop. This is a fun exercise, believe me. :)

Comment: @IgorS It definitely is an option, but I am trying to solve this problem in multiple ways.

Comment: @UltraInstinct I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Try putting a `break` after the `.remove()`.  This will terminate the `for` loop and fall back to the `while` loop, which will terminate if its condition is no longer true.
Also, are you aware that `list.remove(value)` removes the _first_ occurrence of the given value?  If your list contains two occurrences of the same value, and `list[x]` refers to the second one, the wrong one will be removed.  Use `del list[x]` instead.

Comment: @JohnGordon Ah, I knew a break statement had to be put somewhere. Thanks. And yeah, I know. I specifically created the list not to have any multiple occurrences to avoid that issue.

Comment: Btw your newlist will never have number that you are trying to find. Because of this
`if x < number:
            newlist.append(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this bit right here:

```
for x in range(0, len(newlist) - 1):
    if newlist[x] < newlist[round(len(newlist) / 2)]:
        newlist.remove(newlist[x])
```

First, you're iterating over the list

```
[0, 1, 2, ..., len(newlist) - 1]
```

This list is generated *when you start the loop*, meaning that if `len(newlist)` is 7 at the beginning, the list will always go up to 6, regardless of whether things are removed from `newlist`, which you later do. This is what causes your error, since at some point you've removed enough elements that your list is now, say, three elements large, but python is trying to access the fifth element because the list it's iterating over isn't `newlist`, it's `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

To fix this, you could (for example) replace the for loop with this:

```
x = 0
while x < len(newlist - 1):
    if newlist[x] < newlist[round(len(newlist) / 2)]:
        newlist.pop(x)  # simple way of saying "remove item at index x"
```

This is essentially the way of doing a C or Java-style `for` loop in python, and will avoid this type of problem.

I also understand that you have an issue with the logic in your code, which was pointed out in one of the comments above and gets more to the heart of your underlying issue, but this is at least an explanation of why this error occurred in the first place, so maybe it's helpful to you in the future

Comment: Much appreciated.